# Why is max flow algorithm in graph theory correct for maximal bipartite matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite, max-flow

I have read many articles stating that the maximal matching of a bipartite graph can be found using max flow algorithm. But there is a possibility that the matching we get from max flow is not maximal or the matching does not have maximum edges.

Example taken from Competitive Programming Handbook by Anti Laaksonen:
[image: Bipartite Matching]

But if I present the graph in a different manner such that the graph now is:
[image: Changed numbering of vertices]

Then as the algorithm of max flow progresses the matching would be
1----5,
2----7

because 1 simply erases path to the sink but if it would have gone for the edge
1----6
then the matching could have been

1----6,
3----5,
4----7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was with you up until this point:

> Then as the algorithm of max flow progresses the matching would be 1----5, 2----7

What you're describing here isn't actually a maximum flow in the graph. We could push more flow across by sending a unit of flow from 1 to 6, a unit of flow from 2 to 7, and a unit of flow from 3 to 5.

Reading over your question, I think the reason you ended up with the (non-maximum) flow rather than a maximum flow is because of this statement:

> because 1 simply erases path to the sink

From what you're describing here, I'm assuming you're using something like the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm to compute the maximum flow: find an augmenting path from the source to the sink and push flow across it. But Ford-Fulkerson also has a second step here: after pushing flow across an edge, we introduce a *residual* edge in the reverse direction of the flow pushed. This gives the opportunity to "undo" the decision we made in the event that we find a better path.

As a result, after we push a unit of flow from 1 -- 5, we add in a residual edge from 5 back to 1 with a single unit of capacity. That means that the graph now looks like this:

[image: the residual network]

Here, edges in teal flow from s toward t, and edges in purple flow from t back toward s.

Notice that we can "undo" our decision to assign 1 to 5 as follows. Push a unit of flow on the path

> s → 3 → 5 → 1 → 6 → t

to give this flow network:

[image: the updated network]

Now, pushing one more unit of flow on the path

> s → 2 → 7 → t

gives the overall matching 1 -- 6, 2 -- 7, 3 -- 5, which is a maximum matching.

Comment: My doubt is clear now.btw,Is this the only reason we add the reverse edges in graph for max flow or is there any other hidden intention? I used to add the reverse ones only for the sake of algorithm but now I understand their purpose.

Comment: Those reverse edges are added in by the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm in order to ensure it finds a maximum flow. The residual graph is also used in the mathematical proof of the max-flow/min-cut theorem. But if you're treating max-flow as a black box (a graph goes in, the max flow comes out, and you don't care about what the internal operation of the algorithm is) then you don't need to worry about residual edges.

Comment: No. please elaborate your insight on the algorithm. I am doing my Bachelors in Computer Science. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: Residual edges are critical to pretty much any s-t directed max-flow algorithm, they encode what is called a "partially-optimal" solution. Without their use, you could not prove max-flow algorithms converge to the correct answer.